# How to count number of elements in a JSON result with react js

Tags: json, reactjs, api, count

i tried to get the length of my Json response but it doesn't work 
i used "length" with my json result 
this is what i tried in my class in react js :

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:51492/api/CommentSurExperience/GetAllCommentOfExperience/${this.props.passedVal}`)
      .then(res => {
        const persons = res.data;
        const longeur = res.length;
        this.setState({ persons, longeur });
      })
  }
```

then i returned this :

```
<div> <p> { this.state.longeur}</p> </div>
```

but i got an empty result .

how can i count how many elements in my JSON response , please 
thank you for your help.

**********update***********
this is my JSON result using postman
[image]

and this is a capture showing what console.log(res) shows

[image]

Comment: Could you show a sample of what `res` looks like?

Comment: Looks like `res` is a json object and not an array

Comment: @ChrisR i updated my post with a capture of Json result

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare yes it's an array , i updated my post with the Json result

Comment: could you write here result of console.log(res) ?

Comment: If `res` is an array, then you're right to try `res.length`

Comment: thats a postman api call, can you console.log(res)?

Comment: Can you add a reduced test case CodePen?

Comment: @PouyaJabbarisani i added console.log(res) as you said and i got an object result , i updated my post with a capture

Comment: yeah, looks like you got the answer already. its `res.data.length`

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare i added console.log(res) in my   componentDidMount() function and i updated what it shows in my post

Comment: @MaryemSamet did you try `res.data.length`, or, alternatively, `persons.length`?

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare Thank you so much it worked with res.data.length
i just forget to write "data" this is my mistake

Comment: Thank you all for your help , i appreciate that

Comment: @OliverRadini yes now it works with  res.data.length , thank you so much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it should be

```
const longeur = res.data.length;
```

Comment: that made it work  , i just forgot the "data" , thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `res.data.length`. You can see the response schema in Axios [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema).

Comment: that made it work , i just forgot the "data" , thank you so much

Answer (score -2):

You have to specify which key in your state that number belongs to:

```
setState({
  persons: res.data,
  longeur: longeur
})
```

Else it might be because it's res.data.length that you want?

Comment: This notation `this.setState({ persons, longeur });` specifies the key in an implicit way.

Comment: "res.data.length " made it work , i just forgot the "data" , thank you so much

Comment: Well, yes. But he has not really specified what his state variables are called.